# Jquery: get all html source of a page but excluding some #ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use .html() or .contents() but i have strange behaviours

I basically need to get the entire dom of the page, exclude some elements (ex. #first, #second)
and the pass it as a string, not a dom anymore...

is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clone it, remove the elements you want to exclude from the clone, and then return the clone's html:

```
$('body').clone().find('#first,#second').remove().end().html()
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to end() - that'll chop off a few lines of code from future code I write