# jQuery select everything between divs except some tables divs

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the html between two `Divs` for my page except a table which contains hidden values for `jqplot` and also a big `Div` for this `jqplot`. It seems like I should use jQuery `:not()` selector to exclude these two elements. However, my code failed. So could anyone give me some suggestions? Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/FdZHt/), and below is the basic idea of my code. The only stuff I need is contents until the first `table`Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="articles">
    <h2 class="model_header">Exponential Model Output</h2>

    <table align="center">
        <!--end 04uberoutput_start-->
    </table>

    <table width="550" border="1">  
    </table>  
####I need nothing below#####
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <table width="400" border="0" style="display: none">
    </table>

    <div id="chart1" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px; width: 650px; height: 400px; position: relative;" class="jqplot-target">
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
  var jq_html = $("div.articles:not(table&div)").html();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jq_html = $("div.articles").children(':lt(3)');
```

Maybe just target all children with a zero based index lower than 3, to get :

- [0] the H2
- [1] first table
- [2] second table

**EDIT:**

A bit late, did'nt notice the comment !

```
var jq_html = $('<div />').append($("div.articles").children(':lt(3)').clone()).html();
```

Comment: If I add `var jq_html = $("div.articles").children(':lt(3)').html();`, all I got is `Exponential Model Output`. Is there a way to get selected contents in html format?Thanks!

Comment: @tao.hong - edited the answer, and added a solution for that.

Comment: That's is a very neat solution!

Comment: @tao.hong - Thanks, it's the usual way of doing this, appending to a container and then getting the container's html.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an `outerHtml()` function (see [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)). For demonstration purposes, I use the built-in one:

```
var jq = $("div.articles").children(':not(div#chart1,table:hidden)');
var jq_html = "";
jq.each(function() {
  jq_html += $(this)[0].outerHTML + "\n";
});
```

Comment: Thanks.But why I only got `Exponential Model Output ` select?

Comment: If you use `  var jq_html = $("div.articles").children(':not(div#chart1,table:hidden)').html();
`, you will only get `Exponential Model Output `...

Comment: Ah... now I see. From http://api.jquery.com/html/: Get the HTML contents of the **first element** in the set of matched elements

Comment: To get the HTML of the matched elements, you need to iterate over the set (e.g. using http://api.jquery.com/each/), get the HTML using an `outerHtml()` function (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) and then concatenate the output.

Answer (score 1):

from the jquery.api:

In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

So you can only use .html() to retrieve the first element matched anyways. I'll see if I can think of something.

Comment: Thanks! Can those selected HTML elements addable?

Comment: var jq_html = $('body').clone().find('table').remove().end().html()
console.log(jq_html);

I stumbled on this post at the same time I saw similar in the jquery pocket guide:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366382/jquery-get-all-html-source-of-a-page-but-excluding-some-ids